# Spring boot Cookie versus Authorization in header field

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a very minimal `spring-boot` app with dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-security`. I just learned spring boot yesterday. I noticed that sending a `POST` request like below even if provided with the wrong `basic auth` password the request succeeds. Because, of the presence of a cookie in a previous successful request.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/create' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=EA39A09B47575D192845148AFFCAD85B' --data-raw '{
"surname":"Murdock",
"givenname":"John",
"placeofbirth":"Slovenia",
"pin":"1234"
}'
```

Is this the expected behavior? And how do I make `spring-boot` to always check the provided `basic auth` password?

Comment: If you only have `spring-boot-starter-web` there is no security and nor the cookie nor the header are doing anything (well the cookie because you might store something in the session).

Comment: If there is already an authentication in the session a users isn't reauthenticated. You could switch to stateless security (which doesn't store the authentication and requires a valid username/password or token or .. to be provided with each request).